# How to change the frequency of x-axis in R

Tags: r, intervals

I have been working on this project for a week now and am finally plotting my data. 
I want it to display every month name in a vertical fashion instead of just displaying January.

Heres my code

```
plot(dates,as.zoo(dfWkly$ScvCorr26), type="l", xlab="Weeks", ylab=" ",  main = "26 and 52 Week Tracking Errors (%)",col = "red", xaxt="n", axes = FALSE, las= 1)
lines(dates, as.zoo(dfWkly$ScvCorr52), col = "green")
axis.Date(1, dates, format = "%b", las=2)
axis(2, at = seq(0 , 1, .001) )
grid (10,20, lty = 6, col = "lightgrey")
```

My theory: It won't change the intervals because of the format I have it in, at least not the way I normally change the intervals. (with at = seq(......)

So the question. How can I get it to display abbreviations vertically and have every month appear?

Thanks for your help!

-NealC

Answer -

I had to use the date function (not sure if function or package) inside this line.

`at=seq(as.Date("2007-12-31"),max(dates),by=(13*7))`

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to post your data since you have it in a specific format?

Comment: What class is your `dates` object? Call `class(dates)` and let us know. With Date class vector the code you have should do as you wish.

Comment: I got it figured out. Technically not allowed to post data, plus it's thousands of numeric values. :)

Comment: Consider refining your question and posting your answer.  As for posting data, your best bet in that case is to post a small sanitized sample that shares any important properties of your problem data. And be sure to indicate how large the original data set is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming from Google I had to use the date function (not sure if base or package) inside this line.

```
at=seq(as.Date("2007-12-31"),max(dates),by=(13*7))
```